# JavaScript Urls not correctly called after deployment to local host in IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am calling my urls and javascript in this manner: `'/Controller/Action'`, which was working fine in debug mode. When I deployed to IIS in local host all urls are called as `'http://localhost/MyAlias/CurrentController/DesiredController/DesiredAction'` and I am getting a Failed to load resource error. I am also getting the same behavior when using `'../Controller/Action'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';` to ensure they are correctly generated.

Comment: This is not working from Javascript. The generated Url is: `http://localhost/MyAlias/CurrentController/CurrentAction/@Url.Action(%22DesiredAction%22,%20%22DesiredController%22)`

Comment: OK, You must have the script in an external file. You need to generate the value in the main view and pass it to the function in the external file (or add it as a `data-` attribute of the element your handling)

Comment: That's right, because when I used this approach for scripts within the view, it worked fine. But isn't there an easier solution? because both of these solutions require a lot of re-work. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't know what Url.Action is unless Url.Action is called on the razor view. As Stephen mentioned, you may put it on the data- attribute or you could create a javascript variable that will hold your generated Url via Url.Action which should be done on the razor view and then inside your script file you may reference that variable.